# libgdx getChildren

Tags: libgdx

```
        battleStage.addActor(aPlayer.handCard1);
        aPlayer.handCard1.setPosition(300, -256);
        aPlayer.handCard1.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.delay(0),
                Actions.moveTo(300, 50, 1)));
        aPlayer.handCard1.getChildren().items[1].addListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                aPlayer.handCard1.getChildren().items[1].addAction(Actions.hide());
                System.out.println("duh");
            }
        });
```

This is included in a method that is called in my render method.
It doesn't get Clicked. Nothing comes up in my console. I debugged the application and "items[1]" is actually there as a child. It's an Image and when I run the application the Image does show up.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

**edit**

handCard1 is a Group with 2 Image children.

**edit**

I 'm doing `battleStage.addActor(aPlayer.handCard1);` in `show()`
and 
`aPlayer.handCard1.setPosition(300, 50);
        aPlayer.handCard1.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                aPlayer.handCard1.getChildren().items[1].addAction(Actions.hide());
                System.out.println("duh");
            }
        });`
 in `render()` and it's working.

Then I'm doing

```
    aPlayer.handCard1.setPosition(300, 50);
    aPlayer.handCard1.getChildren().items[1].setHeight(256);
    aPlayer.handCard1.getChildren().items[1].setWidth(192);
    aPlayer.handCard1.getChildren().items[1].addListener(new ClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            aPlayer.handCard1.getChildren().items[1].addAction(Actions.hide());
            System.out.println("duh");
        }
    });

}
```

in `render()` and it's not working.

Comment: Are you doing `battleStage.act()` in `render()`?

Comment: If you didn't set width & height, clickListener probabely will not be triggered.

Comment: Yes. `battleStage.act()` is called in `render`. I 'm doing `aPlayer.Card1.getChildren().items[1].setHeight(256);`
`aPlayer.Card1.getChildren().items[1].setWidth(192);` and still nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"This is included in a method that is called in my render method."

You should be adding your actors to the stage in the show() method rather than the render() method.

Comment: Right!! when I called `handCard1.addActor(myActor);` in show method as well as I did for `stage.addActor(myGroup);` it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use actor's setBounds() method set the boundaries for the click event to work. Please check
[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24327860/need-help-in-using-scene2d-button-in-libgdx/24329299)

Comment: Mind that it isn't a button but an Image. Thanks though. Every idea for a possible solution helps me

Comment: I setBounds but it's not working. I discovered that `battleStage.addActor(aPlayer.handCard1);` should be in show method while the rest of this code in render method.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are doing

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(battleStage);
```

and

```
battleStage.act(delta);
```

Comment: Yes I 'm doing `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(battleStage);` in `show()` and `battleStage.act()` in `render()`. I added delta just for the heck of it, nothing happens.